# How to overcome confusion of contrasting word?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, contractions

Actual sentence-
As a result, while patients are not being cured, the malaria parasite continues to spread further.

My Explanation-

This sentence seems to me wrong, because **while** is contrasting word, it is not creating any contrast. With contrasting one side will be positive and other is negative and above sentence both side are negative. How it possible.

I think in this form sentence is right --
As a result, while patients are being cured, the malaria parasite continues to spread further.

In this sentence while is contrasting word, but "not" is going to counter that, 
can we say this sentence in this way

As a result, patients are being cured, the malaria parasite continues to spread further.

Comment: As Ann says, you've got the wrong 'while' in mind. This is not the contrastive version. (However, it might be advisable to rephrase to prevent others falling into the same trap.)

Answer (score 1):

The word "while" means "during the time that," "meanwhile" or "as long as."

So the sentence is trying to say:

"Meanwhile, not curing patients allows the malaria parasite to continue to spread further."

The author intends to say that the failure to cure patients is allowing the further spread of the parasite.

"As long as (while) this situation obtains (namely, that patients are not being cured), the parasite will continue to spread."

The background idea is that the failure to cure patients has repercussions beyond the continuing illness of the patient. The failure to cure also increases the entire problem for the whole of society by allowing the spread of the disease.

Answer (score -1):

Removing the word '**not** being cured' changes the implication of the sentence.  I would rephrase to 'As a result, patients are not being cured and the malaria parasite continues to spread further'.

Comment: why you have not used **while**. The sentence you rephrased is correct .....